# How to reload the same page upon a button click action i.e delete in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reload

I'm using react-router-dom v6 in my project where I just want the admin page to be reloaded whenever admin delete a user but unfortunately unable to do so. found some suggestion of `window.location = "current page"` or `window.location.reload()` also `useNavigate()` but none of them is working in my case the little snippet of code I'm using is this

```js
const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await deleteUser(id);
    window.location="/admin"
  };
```

P.S: delete function is working properly.

Comment: `window.location.reload()` should work. Did you check your API, is it returning success?

Comment: Agree that `window.location.reload` should work in the code you posted. Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-bouman-14bmn Posting more of your code might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Ericgio! As per you said the problem was that I was not sending any response or document back from my server that's why the line window.location.reload() was not being executed because the promise before this line was not resolved. Thanks

Comment: Somebody please create an answer or delete this question, in order to get it out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

You use a great function provided by react-router-dom useHistory you just have to import it like

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

and then you can use it in your code like

```
const onDelete = async (id) => {
    await deleteUser(id);
    history.replace('/admin')
  };
```

now you have to create const history

```
const history = useHistory()
```

now whenever you will call onDelete it will execute and at last it will redirect you to /admin.